# How to fetching an API and using the value obtained in another function?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, async-await, es6-promise, fetch-api

I'm using the new [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) interface from ES6 to obtain the geolocation of the ISS (International Space Station) and render inside a Google Maps, but I don't know how to pass to the other function the value of **iss_position**.

```
export async function currentPosition() {
  const fetchResult = fetch('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json');
  const response = await fetchResult;
  const iss_position = await response.json();
}

export function initMap() {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: iss_position,
    zoom: 5,
  });
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: iss_position,
    map: map,
  });
}

currentPosition();
initMap();
```

Comment: Your `currentPosition` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: I know that! What I need to do modify or change from the first function to expose globally the value of iss_position and access from the second?.

Comment: Call initmap with the value returned by currentPossition  and make sure to return the iss position from currentPossition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
async function currentPosition() {
  const fetchResult = fetch('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json');
  const response = await fetchResult;
  const iss_position = await response.json();
  // Calling initMap with iss_position
  initMap(iss_position);
}

function initMap(iss_position) {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: iss_position,
    zoom: 5,
  });
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: iss_position,
    map: map,
  });
}

currentPosition();

// Please check if this write way to export multiple things or not.
// I'm a NodeJS developer and this is how we do in node.
export = {
    currentPosition,
    initMap
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
async function currentPosition() {
  const fetchResult = fetch('http://api.open-notify.org/iss-now.json');
  const response = await fetchResult;
  const data = await response.json();
  const { latitude, longitude } = data.iss_position;
  initMap(latitude, longitude);
}

function initMap(latitude, longitude) {
  let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    zoom: 5,
  });
  let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: { lat: latitude, lng: longitude },
    map: map,
  });
}

currentPosition();

export { currentPosition, initMap };
```